# Why is there no reponse from ModbusRTU slave using converter?

Tags: communication, rs485, data, modbus, tcp-ip

There are two devices:

1. Eaton **EM20/M** `(~like Northern Design Cube 400)`
2. Volison **ADM-5850G**

Connected them like:

[image: scheme]

Trying to get data from EM20/M which supports ModbusRTU(RS-485) protocol using ADM-5850G converter ModbusTCP<>ModbusRTU.

Converter(ADM-5850G) and Slave(EM20/M) are set for 9600 baud rate.
Also, the converter's settings:

[image: converter]

Some EM20/M's programming pages:

[image: EM20/M]

Created a packet containing `00 01 00 00 00 06 01 03 9e 42 00 01` which should read **1** register at address **40515** from EM20/M which Slave ID is **1**. Register's address got from references below(links).

[image: packet]

Sent same packet using two tools(wireshark shows same result for both tools):

1. **modpoll**(https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)
   Command: `modpoll -a 1 -r 40515 -c 1 -1 192.168.1.104 -l 1000 -o 0.5`
2. **netcat**
   Command: `echo -en "\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x03\x9e\x42\x00\x01" | nc -w 1 192.168.1.104 502`

Result:

1. A **"Cmd"** on EM20/M led blinks one time after command having being sent and there's **no response**:
2. 1 **modpoll** program outputs: `Reply time-out!`:

[image: output]

2. 2 **netcat** just outputs nothing

The question:

Why is there no response?
Do we send a valid packet(also, note that "Cmd" led blinks shortly on EM20/M after command sent)?

References:

1. ModbusTCP: http://www.simplymodbus.ca/TCP.htm
2. EM20/M manual we didn't find, but found Cube 400's: https://www.ndmeter.co.uk/brochures/Manuals/Cube%20400%20Manuals.zip

Comment: "like" Cube400 doesn't make it the same as EM20/M.  aspects of the communications are likely different

Comment: @JonBB, it's visually similar. There's no manuals for EM20/M at all. All aspects from manual of Cube400(programming, menu...) works well with EM20/M.

Comment: Also, as you can see on programming page above(at EM20/M), it shows `Cube Addr` which means it's Cube's firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Try register 515 instead of 40515.  the 4x prefix is just to say "holding registers"  If that doesn't work, try 514, for register addresses vs register numbers.

The "comm light" can blink just because it received a modbus request it understood, but had no answer for.  It's *nice* if devices reply with "illegal register" and it's in the protocol docs, but you can't force devices to follow it.